# Parsing CSV file using TextFieldParser - MalformedLineException

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, csv, parsing

I have following CSV file content:

```
4.1,AB,2018-02-16 15:41:39,152,36,"{"A":{"a1":"A1"},"B":{"b1":"B1}}","{"X":"","Y":"ya"}",20
```

I would like to break/parse it as follows - **comma** is column separator but columns can also have double quotes.

- 4.1
- AB
- 2018-02-16 15:41:39
- 152
- 36
- "{"A":{"a1":"A1"},"B":{"b1":"B1}}"
- "{"X":"","Y":"ya"}"
- 20

This is what I am doing

```
using ( var parser = new TextFieldParser( myCSV ) )
{
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.SetDelimiters( "," );
    parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
    //parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true; 
    // I tried HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes with true and false.

    string[] fields = new string[] { };

    while ( !parser.EndOfData )
        {
                try
                {
                fields = parser.ReadFields();
                }
                catch ( MalformedLineException e)
                {
                   LogError( $"MalformedLineException when parsing CSV" );
                }
        //
        //do something of fields...
    }
}
```

I keep getting MalformedLineException. What is the correct way to ESCAPE the columns which have DOUBLE QUOTES in them such that CSV parser doesn't break them ???

THANK YOU

Comment: the quotes have to be escaped properly for that to be valid csv. For example: `,"{""X"":"""",""Y"":""ya""}",`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;

Since this gets set automatically when setting the delimiter

Comment: Thanks Anthony RajN and Jake - I tried all the options you listed here and in stackoverflow but no success. Note the CSV I get is very different.

Comment: You may be able to fix the issue by making the csv file into an excel file.  I recently used the TextFieldParser class on an excel file and tested with commas and quotes and I got the correct values of the excel fields with no problem.